# Need Laravel package details

Tags: php, laravel

I have a big database schema with lots of tables and fields in Excel format and I want to create a database from this.

Are there any package available for which can convert excel to database?

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel (here is an example: https://hdtuto.com/article/laravel-56-excel-and-csv-import-export-using-maatwebsite-example)

However, for performance, I would recommend you to export Excel file to CSV and parse that one. You can do it with no extra packages, and as you mentioned you have a lot of data, it will be much more efficient.